# Network Connectivity using System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient

Tags: .net, networking, connectivity

Can we use tcpClient to test the network connectivity between the two different servers other than where the programe will run.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple way that send a sample data for test purpose and test this data on other server (validation) if it's the same.

I hope this senario can help you.

Comment: I think you miss understood my question or my question is not clear enough. Anyway i want to use System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient class for testing the connectivity between the two machine by running a program developed using the interface i mentioned above on a third machine.
I think this is more specific question now.